# a proper way to name a method

Tags: angular, typescript

Lately I was reading a lot about best practices in code and what I try to do is "avoid" repetitions.
Can you help name my new function?

```
  filterManufacturers(event) {
    this.filteredManufacturers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.manufacturers.length; i++) {
      let manufacturer = this.manufacturers[i].name;
      if (this.dontKnowHowToNameIt(manufacturer, event)) {
        this.filteredManufacturers.push(manufacturer);
      }
    }
  }

  filterModels(event) {
    this.filteredModels = [];
    for (let manufacturerer of this.manufacturers) {
      if (manufacturerer.name === this.vehicle.manufacturer) {
        for (let model of manufacturerer.models) {
          if (this.dontKnowHowToNameIt(model, event)) {
            this.filteredModels.push(model);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  dontKnowHowToNameIt(input, event) {
    return (input.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.query.toLowerCase()) == 0);
  }
```

Comment: `stringContains` ?

Comment: I was thinking about similar, but usually ppl suggest to avoid using types in names, becuase it is kinda excessive. In other hand naming method as `contains()` seems to be too broad.

Comment: That's opinion based, you're free to name it what you want. But just so you know, that's basically what `String.prototype.includes` do, so it's not really useful ...

Comment: `propertyContainsValueFromEvent` or `propertyContainsQueryFromEvent` would be my choice, but LOL, this question gave me a giggle! :)

Comment: @Emaro thanks, definitly will post it there next time.

Comment: @Emaro With the current lack of context, absolutely not. OP will have to read [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and make modifications before even considering posting it there.

Comment: @JohnWeisz I'm glad I could make you smile :)

Comment: @Mast I just recommended to post this *type* of questions there. Not to copy this question directly to Code Review. As I'm not very experienced: Do you think the question better fits on SO than on Code Review? For me it's clearly a code style / clean code question.

Comment: @Emaro Did you read the help center? Honestly, it isn't a good fit on SO either. I'm not sure the question should be asked in this format at all.

Comment: @Mast, yeah, I agree. It could fall under best practices though.

Comment: @Emaro It would fail the checklist.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily opinion based question, but let's answer it.

To name it something `isInFilter` makes more sense, because you are being very restrictive by using the `event.query` inside the function.

Another word of advice is to look into the more specific string and array methods of javascript. You are using angular and typescript, so you can use whatever you like (most of the time):

```
filterManufacturers(event) {
  return this.manufacturers.filter(({ name }) => this.isInFilter(name, event.query));
}

filterModels(event) {
  return this.manufacturers
    .filter(({ name }) =>  this.isInFilter(name, this.vehicle.manufacturer))
    .map(({ models }) => models)
    .filter((model) => this.isInFilter(model, event.query))
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), []);
}

isInFilter(input, query) {
  return input.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
}
```

This will simplify your code because less nesting (`{{}{}}`) occurs

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function and call it everytime you need and to less repetition.

```
 function toLoop(x, y) {
         for (i of y) {
           if (i.id === x.id) {
             return y.indexOf(i);
           }
}  return -1;}
```

and you call it on the other function..

```
 if (toLoop(r, resp[key]) === -1) {
      resp[key].push(r);
    }
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't really answer the question itself.